# Persisting to multiple databases in Spring

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, distributed-transactions, atomikos

We have a DB2 database which is used by legacy applications that we are in the process of decommissioning and we have an Oracle database that we are developing new applications for. In order to maintain compatibility with legacy applications until they are completely decommissioned and keep data in sync, we are using Atomikos for two phase commits. This however is resulting in a lot of duplicated entities and repositories and thus technical debt, because the same entities and repositories cannot be used by the same entity managers so we have to duplicate them and put them under different packages for the entity scanning.

In most cases we want to read data from the legacy database and persist to both, but ideally this would be configurable.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.